# Android setOnItemClickListener vs setOnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

As I know, there are two methods to handle click on different list items:

1. Use `setTag()` to set types for items of list in Adapter, then `setOnItemClickListener()` for the list and `getTag()` of the view to differentiate the type, like this:

`listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClcikListener(){});`

2. Inside the adapter, `setOnClickListener()` individually for each item during `getView()`, like this:

`item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {});`

What is the difference and which one is preferred?

Comment: Imho you will need one `setOnItemClickListener` and a lot of `setOnClickListener`... So.... What do you think is best? I would say `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Plese check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044447/difference-between-onclicklistener-and-onitemclicklistener

Comment: @SabinJose Sorry I did not explain clearly. What I mean is the OnClickListener of the row not the listview. So this question is not the same as your link.

Comment: @SabinJose Actually it's the same as the comment vandus left below the answer of your link.

Comment: @PedroOliveira You mean for the second solution is setting clickListener for each row? Does it affect the performance?

Comment: plz check here for answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936176....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936176/difference-in-listview-setonitemclicklistener-and-row-setonclicklistener) you will get good explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnItemClickListener` is very easy to manage compare to `OnClickListener`.
If you still would love to manage `OnClickListener` I will tell why `OnItemClickListener` is much better than  `OnClickListener`.

**Once you start scrolling `ListView` items will start getting reused and you ended up creating lot of `OnClickListener`. Don't worry, this is not a memory leak as GC will come into picture and collect those but you should not feel safe also because `GC pauses your activity` even if it is fraction of second that's considerable.**

So would I go with `OnItemClickListener` *unless you planned something different for individual list item.*

If you need to create specific portions of each item to be clickable or want more than one action to be performed for a given item, it would be best if possible to collect those actions into a single OnClickListener that is created once and then attached to each item in getView(). You can differentiate which item was clicked by attaching metadata about the click action and maybe list position to the views themselves with setTag().

Comment: In my case I need to call different actions for individual items. Is it still better to use setOnItemClickListener() with Tag in this situation? BTW I will look at the source code.

Comment: As I debugged for list scrolling, I didn't see the GC for item recycle, is it because my list, 10 items, is not long enough?

Comment: 10 items is very small list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i really understood what do you mean but i will try to give you a reply.

> Use setTag() to set types for items of list in Adapter, then setOnItemClickListener() for the list and getTag() of the view to differentiate the type, like this:
>   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClcikListener(){});

You can use `setTag()` for set an `Object` like a tag, it means you can use it to put some informations into your cell view (ex: text, id and so on).
To "differentiate the type" of your view i would suggest you to use `getViewTypeCount().

> inside the adapter, setOnClickListener() individually for each item during getView(), like this:
>   item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {});

This actually depends more on what you want to do with your list, if the behaviour of the click is strictly related to the informations which belong to your adapter or for example if you have a button inside your cell view, then set a listener for the cell view inside the adapter could be a good solution.
But except for the last case i would say the first is the best solution, since you can put everything you want into your tag, and it gives you the chance to manage your list's click from your main `Activity` or `Fragment`.